# Datetime fields datetime inputs javascript and django not compatible

Tags: javascript, django, datetime

I have a model that consists of a DateTimeField. The DateTimeField is aware.

so

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    #fields
    start = models.DateTimeField()
```

I also have a model form from my model

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Model
```

When a MyModelForm is rendered on the page from an existing model like

```
form = MyModelForm(instance=my_model)
```

it renders the input using a text input. I am also using bootstrap datetimepicker to turn this in to a nice looking datetime picker. The problem is that if I try to alter the date on the input box from javascript, and save it says that its not a valid date.

js code

```
newStartDate = new Date();
start_input = document.getElementById('datetimepicker1');
start_input.prop('value', newStartDate());
```

The input box when rendered from django has the time in this format

```
2014-01-14 13:00
```

and js produces these

```
start_date.toLocaleString(): "14/1/2014 12:50:24 μ.μ."
```

The only way was to create the datetime string my self like this

```
start_date = start_date.getFullYear() + '-' + start_date.getMonth()+1+'-'+start_date.getDate()+' '+start_date.getHours() + ':' + start_date.getMinutes()
```

Isn't there a better way to deal with it or should I always construct this string

Comment: Have you tried to send [`input_formats`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.DateTimeField.input_formats) parameter to `DateTimeField` construnctor? Notice that this is not the best option if you allow user to enter date by hand in an internationalized environment.

Comment: What is the best way? The date time is saved in utc on the database as the Django Tutorial about time zones suggests http://goo.gl/8CVFYs

Comment: Best way is all, 'regional culture', django and javascript works with date format in same way. Your datetimepicker [should be parametrizable](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#timezone_examples).